# How to make a PHP server websocket work on a domain?

Tags: php, heroku, websocket, server, upload

I have a WebSocket server, but I don't know how to make it work outside my local host. Currently, I have to direct the CMD to the project location and run the server with the command "php -q server.php", but obviously users won't have to do that. For this reason, I started searching and found Heroku, but I'm not able to upload it there. The idea is to run a .sh file through Procfile, the .sh file will activate the command "php server.php"; and after that a file called nginx_app.conf will replace localhost:812 for the domain URL, but when I upload the project to Heroku, it doesn't accept and requires composer.json, but my project doesn't depend on it. Does anyone know how I can make this WebSocket work the same or another way?

Comment: Are you asking how to deploy your websocket application on a public server? You need to host it in a server which allows you to run background processes and set them to run as a daemon (or at least have a daemon which is there to restart the socket server if it does). You might need a VPS, not many shared hosting accounts would allow this. Not sure about cloud, a VM there might be what you need.

Comment: Yes, I need to deploy my project and I try to use the heroku.

Comment: Not possible using heroku and PHP (but possible using other languages) -https://help.heroku.com/8R7OO0ZV/can-i-run-a-websockets-server-using-php-on-heroku . (P.s. it might have been a good idea to Google that beforehand?)

Comment: do you know where i can run my php server? I've already searched on google, but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: Like I said in my first comment you might need to rent a whole server (VPS - virtual private server) so you can install and run whatever you like on it. Or you might be able to do it via some cloud hosting. Most cheap shared hosting would not allow it I don't think, but you'd have to research carefully, each provider may offer slightly different things.

Answer (score 0):

> localhost:812

You will need to add a firewall entry to allow your listening port: 812.

linux it's
sudo ufw allow 812

Remove the listening port
sudo ufw delete allow 812

check your system to make sure no other apps are using that port with
sudo netstat -tunlp

A VPS will allow you to open ports and install any applications you need, they start as low as a few dollars a month.